# footnotes in boxes compatible with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, expl3

I am trying to implement a support for `\footnote` in a horizontal list (boxed)
environment based on `shortlst` and ported (more less) to `expl3`. The
trick used in `shortlst` is taken from the `tabularx` package and goes
something like this:

```
% Code Part I
\ifx\TX@ftn\undefined
   \newtoks\TX@ftn
   \long\def\TX@ftntext#1{%
     \edef\@tempa{\the\TX@ftn\noexpand\footnotetext
                       [\the\csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname]}%
     \global\TX@ftn\expandafter{\@tempa{#1}}}%
   \long\def\TX@xftntext[#1]#2{%
     \global\TX@ftn\expandafter{\the\TX@ftn\footnotetext[#1]{#2}}}
\fi
% Code Part II
\global\TX@ftn\expandafter{\expandafter}\the\TX@ftn
% Code Part III
\let\@footnotetext\TX@ftntext\let\@xfootnotenext\TX@xftntext
```

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,lua-visual-debug}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\IfPackageLoadedTF { hyperref }
  {
    \legacy_if:nT { Hy@hyperfootnotes } { \typeout{hyperfootnotes=true} }
  }{ }
% copy footnote
\cs_new_eq:NN \__my_footnotetext:nn \footnotetext
\cs_new_eq:NN \__my_footnotet:n \footnote
% \NewCommandCopy \__my_footnotet:n \footnote
% Redefine
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_renew_footnote:
  {
    \RenewDocumentCommand \footnote { o +m }
      {
        \IfNoValueTF {##1}
           {
             %\stepcounter{footnote}
             %\footnotemark[ \int_use:c { c@footnote } ]
             \tl_gset:Ne \g_tmpa_tl
               {
                 %\exp_not:N \__my_footnotetext:nn [ \int_use:c { c@footnote } ] {##2}
                 \exp_not:N \__my_footnotet:n {##2}
               }
           }
           {
             \footnotemark[##1]
             \tl_gset:Ne \g_tmpa_tl
               {
                 \exp_not:N \__my_footnotetext:nn [##1] {##2}
               }
           }
      }
  }
% Environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{}
  {
    \group_begin:
      \lrbox{ \l_tmpa_box }
      \__my_renew_footnote:
  }
  {
      \endlrbox
    \group_end:
    \box_set_wd:Nn \l_tmpa_box { 0.75\linewidth }
    \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
    % footnote
    \tl_if_empty:NF \g_tmpa_tl
      {
        \g_tmpa_tl
        \tl_gclear:N \g_tmpa_tl
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Test here \footnote{footnote numered 1.}
\begin{test}
This is a test \footnote{footnote numbered 2.} more text
\end{test}
\begin{test}
This is a test \footnote[5]{footnote numered 5}.
\end{test}
This is a test \footnote{footnote numbered 3.}.
\end{document}
```

I can't get the marks in the right place when loading hyperref...any way to get around this?

**First attempt**

With this version I get the markings and numbering to be just what I want, but, now I get:

```
warning  (pdf backend): unreferenced destination with name 'Hfootnote.2'
```

So I get out of one...and stay in another :(

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\IfPackageLoadedTF { hyperref }
  {
    \legacy_if:nT { Hy@hyperfootnotes } { \typeout{hyperfootnotes=true} }
  }{ }
% copy footnote
\cs_new_eq:NN \__my_footnotetext:nn \footnotetext
% Redefine (based on https://latexref.xyz/Footnotes-in-a-table.html)
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_renew_footnote:
  {
    \RenewDocumentCommand \footnote { o +m }
      {
        \IfNoValueTF {##1}
           {
             \int_gset_eq:Nc \g_tmpa_int { c@footnote }
             \footnotemark
             \tl_gset:Ne \g_tmpa_tl
               {
                 \int_gincr:N \g_tmpa_int
                 \exp_not:N \__my_footnotetext:nn [ \g_tmpa_int ] {##2}
               }
           }
           {
             \footnotemark[##1]
             \tl_gset:Ne \g_tmpa_tl
               {
                 \exp_not:N \__my_footnotetext:nn [##1] {##2}
               }
           }
      }
  }
% Environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{}
  {
    \group_begin:
      \lrbox{ \l_tmpa_box }
      \__my_renew_footnote:
  }
  {
      \endlrbox
    \group_end:
    \box_set_wd:Nn \l_tmpa_box { 0.75\linewidth }
    \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
    % footnote
    \tl_if_empty:NF \g_tmpa_tl
      {
        \g_tmpa_tl
        \tl_gclear:N \g_tmpa_tl
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Test here \footnote{footnote numered 1.}
\begin{test}
This is a test \footnote{footnote numbered 2.} more text
\end{test}
\begin{test}
This is a test \footnote[5]{footnote numered 5}.
\end{test}
This is a test \footnote{footnote numbered 3.}.
\end{document}
```

**NOTE**

I will leave this here as a note for future users.
My original idea was to be able to support `\footnote` inside boxes and have it be compatible with `hyperref`, preferably without using third party packages, but it's not that simple. The solution presented by @cfr fits perfect, just a couple of conditionals and we have `hyperref` support without major problems :D

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\makesavenoteenv{test}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% vars
\box_new:N \l__pgl_footnote_box
\int_new:N \g__pgl_footnote_int
\seq_new:N \g__pgl_footnotes_seq
\seq_new:N \g__pgl_footnotenos_seq
\bool_new:N \l__pgl_hyper_foot_key_bool
% hyperref
\IfPackageLoadedTF { hyperref }
  {
    \legacy_if:nT { Hy@hyperfootnotes }
      {
        \typeout{hyperfootnotes=true}
        \bool_set_true:N \l__pgl_hyper_foot_key_bool
      }
  }{ }
\bool_if:NT \l__pgl_hyper_foot_key_bool
  {
    \IfPackageLoadedTF { footnotehyper }
      {
         \typeout{OK ~ hyperref ~ and ~ footnotehyper}
      }
      {
         \typeout{No ~ footnotehyper ~ load}
         \typeout{Load ~ and  ~ use  ~ \string\makesavenoteenv{test}}
         \bool_set_false:N \l__pgl_hyper_foot_key_bool
      }
  }

% copy footnote
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_footnotetext:nn
  {
    \footnotetext[#1]{#2}
  }
% Redefine (based on https://latexref.xyz/Footnotes-in-a-table.html)
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_renew_footnote:
  {
    \seq_gclear:N \g__pgl_footnotes_seq
    \seq_gclear:N \g__pgl_footnotenos_seq
    \RenewDocumentCommand \footnote { o +m }
      {
        \IfNoValueTF {##1}
          {
            \stepcounter{footnote}
            \int_gset_eq:Nc \g__pgl_footnote_int { c@footnote }
          }
          {
            \int_gset:Nn \g__pgl_footnote_int { ##1 }
          }
            \footnotemark[\g__pgl_footnote_int]
            \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__pgl_footnotes_seq  { ##2 }
            \seq_gput_right:NV \g__pgl_footnotenos_seq  \g__pgl_footnote_int
     }
  }
% Environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{}
  {
    \group_begin:
    \lrbox{ \l__pgl_footnote_box }
    \bool_if:NF \l__pgl_hyper_foot_key_bool
      {
        \__my_renew_footnote:
      }
  }
  {
    \endlrbox
    \group_end:
    \box_set_wd:Nn \l__pgl_footnote_box { 0.75\linewidth }
    \box_use:N \l__pgl_footnote_box
    % footnote
    \seq_if_empty:NF \g__pgl_footnotenos_seq
      {
        \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN \g__pgl_footnotenos_seq \g__pgl_footnotes_seq \__my_footnotetext:nn
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Test here \footnote{footnote numbered 1.}
\begin{test}
  This is a test \footnote{footnote numbered 2.} more text\footnote{Another footnote.}
\end{test}
\begin{test}
  This is a test \footnote[5]{footnote numbered 5}.
\end{test}
This is a test \footnote{footnote numbered 4.}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Out]

Comment: sorry but your example is way to long. If I got it right you want footnotes that can escape boxes and all this list code is not relevant.  Side-remark: be aware that in the latex-lab code for the tagging project the footnote code has been rewritten (you load it with `\DocumentMetadata{testphase=new-or}` or some later phase), including the hyperref support. So don't rely too much on internals.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I removed the unnecessary from the example and rephrased the question.

Comment: Yes I saw it and it is imho fine, but I don't have time now, remind me in a few days if you didn't get an answer from someone else.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have placed an attempt that works almost as I want it to, only I get `warning  (pdf backend): unreferenced destination with name 'Hfootnote.2'`...could you take a look at it when you have some time?

Comment: Do you expect them to be hyperlinked or do you just want the marks to be correct?

Comment: Actually I expect both if `hyperref` is loaded with the `[hyperfootnotes=true]` option, but the numbering is the most important thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let me know if I should delete this.**

This produces the marks and texts you want without `hyperref` warnings about either undefined or multiply defined destinations. It also permits multiple footnotes in a box and eliminates the use of standard temporary variables.

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700092/ i gwestiwn Pablo González L: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699441/
\usepackage{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\IfPackageLoadedTF { hyperref }
{
  \legacy_if:nT { Hy@hyperfootnotes } { \typeout{hyperfootnotes=true} }
}{ }
\box_new:N \l__gpl_footnote_box
\int_new:N \g__pgl_footnote_int
\seq_new:N \g__pgl_footnotes_seq
\seq_new:N \g__pgl_footnotenos_seq
% copy footnote
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_footnotetext:nn {\footnotetext[#1]{#2}}
% Redefine (based on https://latexref.xyz/Footnotes-in-a-table.html)
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_renew_footnote:
{
  \seq_gclear:N \g__pgl_footnotes_seq
  \seq_gclear:N \g__pgl_footnotenos_seq
  \RenewDocumentCommand \footnote { o +m }
  {
    \IfNoValueTF {##1}
    {
      \stepcounter{footnote}
      \int_gset_eq:Nc \g__pgl_footnote_int { c@footnote }
    }
    {
      \int_gset:Nn \g__pgl_footnote_int { ##1 }
    }
    \footnotemark[\g__pgl_footnote_int]
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__pgl_footnotes_seq  { ##2 }
    \seq_gput_right:NV \g__pgl_footnotenos_seq  \g__pgl_footnote_int
  }
}
% Environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{}
{
  \group_begin:
  \lrbox{ \l__gpl_footnote_box }
  \__my_renew_footnote:
}
{
  \endlrbox
  \group_end:
  \box_set_wd:Nn \l__gpl_footnote_box { 0.75\linewidth }
  \box_use:N \l__gpl_footnote_box
  % footnote
  \seq_if_empty:NF \g__pgl_footnotenos_seq
  {
    \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN \g__pgl_footnotenos_seq \g__pgl_footnotes_seq \__my_footnotetext:nn
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Test here \footnote{footnote numbered 1.}
\begin{test}
  This is a test \footnote{footnote numbered 2.} more text\footnote{Another footnote.}
\end{test}
\begin{test}
  This is a test \footnote[5]{footnote numbered 5}.
\end{test}
This is a test \footnote{footnote numbered 4.}.
\end{document}
```

[image: two boxes with three footnotes and non-boxes with two footnotes]

[image: five footnotes]

Comment: Great, now the numbering is correct :D, but I lose the links for `\footnote{text}` (without the optional argument which is the default support if `hyperref` whit [hyperfootnotes=true])...can try to adapt the code from (https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/aa373a0a17e2f5080d9d1e40389abe5fc068870c)

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Hyperref manual page 56? Not `expl3`, though.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL I should delete? Unsure if 'Great' is sarcastic ....

Comment: @crf No, don't delete it, the link to Git shows a way to make it work with hyperref...I'm not being sarcastic at all, your version is much better than the use of `tl_` that I had proposed.

Comment: @crf Thank you very much for the answer, the rest I can solve with the help of the `footnotehyper` package (I think it is more complicated than I thought to have direct support for `hyperref` from expl3).

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Great! Do note you're misspelling my user name. If somebody else commented, I wouldn't get pinged.

Comment: Yes, I just realized it when I was writing in the chat...a thousand apologies and thanks again :D